# Exclude products which are in more than one category from Cart Price Rules

Tags: category, discount

I have a problem with Magento 2. We have products in more than one category. Now we would like to create a cart price rule, but we would like to exclude products for which one of the categories is marked.

For example:
We have product X, which is in Categories 'Women Clothing' and 'Sale' and
we have product Y which is only in the category 'Women Clothing'.
We want to create a cart price rule that exclude products which are in 'Sale'.
So for this example product X should be excluded from the discount.

I have tried creating a cart price rule, but as product X is in more than one category the product is not excluded from the discount.

Can somebody help me figure this out please?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards, Niels

Answer (score 0):

Attached is a screenshot of what this looks like. Notice how you won't be using the "Conditions" tab. Instead, under "Actions", you will want to apply the conditions in "Apply the rule only to cart items...".

So, as an example to answer your question, if you want to apply a fixed amount discount of $20 to all products in "Women's Clothing" (id 27 in this case), you would add the first condition "Category **is one of** 27". It's important to notice the condition "is one of". If you selected "is", the rule wouldn't apply as you're intending it to... Then, to exclude products that are also in the "Sale" category, you would apply the second condition "Category **is not one of** 183".

[image: Cart price rule, excluding by category]